# Heroku Deploy Error (404 Not Found: websocket-driver@0.7.2)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I got this problem when deploying node app with Heroku. Do you guys have any idea why? I added a version to node package. Thanks

```
remote: npm ERR! code E404
remote: npm ERR! 404 Not Found: websocket-driver@0.7.2
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.LyT4h/_logs/2019-07-11T16_47_07_315Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! rental@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `cd client && npm install && npm run build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the rental@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.LyT4h/_logs/2019-07-11T16_47_07_430Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

Comment: go through the link, it helped me `https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [websocket-driver was not found on deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56718056/websocket-driver-was-not-found-on-deploy)

Comment: Specifically, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56718624/354577)